# Scan special key through socket

Tags: go, sockets, tcp, keyboard

I developed a little application, that serves through TCP socket; all works fine, but I'd like to do a step more: is it possible to catch special keys (like UP arrow, DOWN arrow, Fx function, ecc.) through a socket?

Comment: A socket is only a transport for data. It does not catch keyboard data. Catching of the special keys, i.e. the transformation of event to data, has to be done outside the socket.

Comment: No, TCP only sends bytes, not keys.